# Rails 3: How to save uploaded images to assets directory and how to display them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, carrierwave

I followed the Railscast about Carrierwave: http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

I looked in the Carrierwave Wiki: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-To%3A-Secure-Upload

I have also Googled the question and can't find the answer.

I'm trying to save uploaded images into the assets directory (to they can be more secured and not accessed by everyone) and then display them in a webpage.

I tried this...

```
Rails.root + "app/assets/images/uploads/children/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
```

... which does save it in the assets directory, but then I'm having a hard time displaying the image in a webpage.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload:

```
File.open(Rails.root.join('app/assets', 'app_banners', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |f|
  f.write(uploaded_io.read)
end
```

where `uploaded_io` is your `$_FILES` variable and `app_banners` is folder under `assets`

For display you can use

where image.png is put in any folder in assets auto detect and display.. on your webpage..